# Spring ResponseEntity return server error when return Iterable & Page result

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, elasticsearch

I've received **"The server encountered an error processing the request."** error when try to return Iterable & Page result via ResponseEntity. I'm having this issue since I upgrade to **Spring Web MVC 4.2.4**.

My Spring WEB MVC Version :

[image]

Sample Codes (getting data from Elasticsearch) :

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/user/{usernamesearchstring}", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ResponseEntity<Iterable<User>> searchUser(@PathVariable("userNameSearchString") String userNameSearchString) {

  QueryBuilder builder = QueryBuilders.prefixQuery("userName", userNameSearchString);

  Iterable<User> user =  userElasticsearchRepository.search(builder);

  HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();

  return new ResponseEntity<Iterable<User>>(user, headers, HttpStatus.OK);

}
```

**Note :**

1. Before upgrade to Spring Web MVC 4.2.4, the same codes above successfully return the result.
2. I've tested to return Page and getting the same error as well

Comment: Shouldn't the `query` variable be named `builder`?

Comment: it seems to be compilation issue. query & builder !

Comment: Hi @Val, yeah you're right. I've pasted the wrong code here. Actually in my real code, its already `builder` variable. I **successfully get the result from Elasticsearch** but the problem is at the ResponseEntity line.

Comment: What stack trace do you get in your server log?

Comment: hi @Val, sorry for the delay reply. my server log didn't show anything. no error message at all. i use this workaround for now - converting Iterable object to List - List<User> userList = new ArrayList<User>().